# trying to understand ternary ?: Vs. double bar || ? Assign first non null value

Tags: javascript

My goal is to check if a cookie exists, if it does get it's value and re-add it with updated date. If it does not exist (first pageview of session) then generate a random number and apply it's value to the cookie.

Below are small bits of script. The syntax {{somestring}} is Google-Tag-Manager syntax and it's just referencing a function which returns a value.

```
{{random number}} //returns a random number
{{hform_num cookie}} //returns the value of cookie hform_num
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes (approx 1 in 5) the value of my cookie is undefined. It should always have a numeric value. I've tried playing with different syntax and code structure. I recently learned about ternary operator so gave that a try as shown below. I've also tried var `somevar = something || something_else` to get first non null value. But I still see the odd undefined get through.

Here's some snippets:

```
var rn = {{random number}}; 
var hcook = {{hform_num cookie}}; // might be null
var num = hcook || rn;

document.cookie='hform_num=' + num + '; path=/; domain=.example.com; expires=' + date + ';';
```

Here's a similar bit of script:

```
var rn = {{random number}}; 
var hcook = {{hform_num cookie}}; // might be null
var num = hcook ? hcook : rn;

document.cookie='hform_num=' + num + '; path=/; domain=.example.com; expires=' + date + ';';
```

And here's another one:
Here's a similar bit of script:

```
var num = {{hform_num cookie}} ? {{hform_num cookie}} : {{random number}};

document.cookie='hform_num=' + num + '; path=/; domain=.example.com; expires=' + date + ';';
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here? Is my code "sound"? Is there a conventional way of declaring two vars then assigning a value to a new var based on first non null value of the two vars?

Comment: *But I still see the odd undefined get through.* That should never happen regardless of whether you use `?` or `||`. `undefined` is falsy. So your problem must be happening somewhere else. Is it possible the `{{random number}}` is returning `undefined`?

Comment: Hi Matt, I should add that the environment I'm in, Google-Tag-Maager will return "undefined" as a string if it returns a falsy variable

Comment: Not sure I follow you there. But if you have the string `"undefined"` then that's obviously NOT falsy. So `"undefined"||someothervalue` will always give you the *string* `"undefined"`

Comment: `x || y` is effectively identical to `x ? x : y` so use whichever one you like better.

Comment: Sounds like my syntax is fine so it must be an issue with my Google-Tag_manager variables {{random number}} and {{hform_num cookie}}. I'll look there, thanks for the feedback on my code.

Comment: And note that `x && y` is the same as `x ? y : x`

Comment: @pointy OK... so is there any caveats to using && in this context? It's less typing so presumably preferred?

Comment: No downside, so again go with what feels right. Exploiting the (somewhat uniquely among C-like languages) interesting JavaScript behaviors of `||` and `&&` is fairly idiomatic.